# Does DocumentBuilder.parse close the InputStream

Tags: java, xml, inputstream

For code similar to the following:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputstream("test.xml");
Document doc = DocumentBuilder.parser(is);
```

My question is whether I need to close the stream manually (invoke is.close()). Does DocumentBuilder close the InputStream for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following test code to see whether the input stream is closed or not, and you could see which line of code closes the stream.

```
public class DocumentBuilderTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
     InputStream is = new MyInputStream("project.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
     documentBuilder.parse(is);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }

 static class MyInputStream extends FileInputStream {   
   public MyInputStream(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
     super(filename);
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws IOException {
     // here we log when the stream is close.
     System.out.println("file input stream closed.");
     Exception e = new Exception();
     e.printStackTrace();
     super.close();
   }

 }
}
```

Whether the input stream passed to the DocumentBuilder is closed or not depends on the DOMParser implementation. In my environment, the file input stream is closed, see the stack trace below:

```
at DocumentBuilderTest$MyInputStream.close(DocumentBuilderTest.java:37)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.close(XMLEntityManager.java:3047)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.close(UTF8Reader.java:661)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.Entity$ScannedEntity.close(Entity.java:441)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1406)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1763)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(XMLEntityScanner.java:1543)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
at DocumentBuilderTest.main(DocumentBuilderTest.java:22)
```

So you could not manually close the stream in this specific example.  However, it is always a good idea to close input stream when you are sure that the stream will not be used any more. In your case, once the document is parsed, the input stream is no longer needed, so the stream could be safely closed, and I suggest you do that.

Answer (score 6):

The usual contract is that code that acquires a resource must release it. This is good practice as it means that if an exception is thrown by any intervening code, you don't leak the resource.

Use a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block:

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("foo")) {
  // process data
}
```

For pre-Java 7:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("foo");
try {
  // process data
} finally {
  in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What I did is to extend FilterInputStream, and override close() method implementation to prevent closing the InputStream

```
public class HackInputStream
    extends FilterInputStream {

    public HackInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // this does not close stream.
        // use hackedClose() instead.
    }

    public void hackedClose() 
            throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation makes no mention of it closing the stream, and I would not expect it to close the stream for you.

To be certain, you could read the source code, or check if it's open in a simple example case after calling parse().

But the short answer: Yes, you need to manually close it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! I'll make a simple example.

Comment: No problem. Also, I would assume that without explicitly saying so, the method would not close it.  I expect methods acting on objects I pass them to act on the objects as little as possible. Calling .close() would be seen as a breach of responsibility to me (the parse method has no business calling .close()).

Comment: To my surprise, DocumentBuilder.parse close the stream in my example.

Comment: Interesting... I would not have expected that.  I feel like they should note that in their documentation, though I guess technically it's implementation specific.  I guess they figure once an InputSteam is at the end, what is the purpose of leaving it open.

Comment: Yes, it closes stream and it makes a problem that i can not proceed working with this stream anymore.

Comment: I really don't understand why it closes the stream.  It seems to me like that class is overstepping its bounds in doing that.  If you look at how it's implemented though, it's a giant tree of classes, so maybe they reused a wrapper around InputStream and its actually the wrapper closing it, not the DocumentBuilder (which may or may not make sense depending on the wrapper -- still seems odd to me).

Answer (score 0):

If your need was to have your stream not closed after DOM parsing (in order to be able to continue to read it, for example), see this thread :
[Java create InputStream from ZipInputStream entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020982/java-create-inputstream-from-zipinputstream-entry/20021172#20021172)